# How do I change the timeout when connecting on remote desktop while a session is in use? server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

When I connect it kicks another user off, but first a dialogue appears saying someone else is trying to connect. They can press OK, or after 30 seconds it will automatically connect.

Is there a way to change this value from 30 seconds to 10 seconds? I couldn't see it in the terminal services settings.

Comment: Why not use different logins instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked and looked through the Group Policy settings, but I haven't found anything that would appear to help.  I think it will probably require a registry hack, but I don't know what key.

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server [NotificationTimeOut]  Looks promising, but I am unable to test it.